# Workflow won't switch back to text-Based Designer

Tags: workflow

I setup a Workflow using the text-Based Designer.  It was working as expected, but I wanted to get a Visio Export and print out a visual of the flow.   Now I can not return to text-based designer.   It is complaining that a workflow shape is not attach to workflow, but I don't see where the problem is?  Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to delete the last page of my workflow.  After that I was able to bring it back to the text-based designer.  Then I was able to add the part I had deleted.